# Quickfix python: memory leak on UtcTimeStamp

Tags: python, swig, quickfix

I started using the library [quickfix](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix) and I faced an issue using the python version:

```
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'UtcTimeStamp *', no destructor found
```

And when I go to the source code in C++ of the library I can see that the class `FIX::UtcTimeStamp` don't have any destructor ([FieldTypes.h:583](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/0b88788710b6b9767440cd430bf24c6b6e2080a2/src/C%2B%2B/FieldTypes.h#L583)).

Is it a false positive? or a real error and in this case should I modify internaly the source code of `quickfix`?

`Python3` version: `3.10.4`
`pip` version: `22.0.2`
`quickfix` version: `1.15.1`

> The `quickfix` library was not build localy, but installed directly with `pip`.

> I'm not good enough in python to know how to trace back the memory leak, don't hesitate to post how in the comment and I will edit the question with the related information.

##### Edit:

- After checking the documentation [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) in C++, it's possible to have a implicit one. So the issue doesn't come from there.

Answer (score 0):

Destructor is probably [there](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/0b88788710b6b9767440cd430bf24c6b6e2080a2/src/C%2B%2B/FieldTypes.h#L103).

You probably compiled the module in a wrong way.
Maybe you could provide more info on how you had this error, and which version of Python and quickfix you are using by doing so:

```
$ pip list | grep quickfix
quickfix                    1.15.1
$ python --version
Python 3.8.17
```

With the above version the following is working without any memory leak:

```
>>> from quickfix import UtcTimeStampField
>>> UtcTimeStampField(1)
<quickfix.UtcTimeStampField; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'FIX::UtcTimeStampField *' at 0x7fa0131d4960> >
```